# "__weak MyClass *myWeakClass = self" using myWeakClass VS using self

Tags: ios, objective-c, self, weak-references

I am trying to learn AVFoundation sample code "AVCam". In the sample code project, AVCamViewController.m class, there is an implementation like

```
__weak AVCamViewController *weakSelf = self;
[self setRuntimeErrorHandlingObserver:[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:AVCaptureSessionRuntimeErrorNotification
                                                                                            object:[self session]
                                                                                             queue:nil
                                                                                        usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
AVCamViewController *strongSelf = weakSelf;
```

My question is why we want to first declare a __weak pointer, and later on assign  this weak pointer to *strongSelf. What would be the difference that if we assign "self" directly
Something like:

```
AVCamViewController *strongSelf = self
```

Whole code 
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/AVCam/Listings/AVCam_AVCamViewController_m.html

Comment: @jemmons explained it in details:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/20032131/846780

Comment: Check this answer, you can better understand 

http://stackoverflow.com/a/28876222/4631833

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we pass self it could lead to a retain cycle under certain conditions (For example some object may have strong reference to the block and self might have strong reference to that object). Passing weak reference into the block guarantees absence of such a retain cycle. But we still may need to keep self alive while block is executed. That's why we assign weak reference to a strong one.

Conclusion: passing weak reference into a block and assinging it to a strong reference retains object for the time of block execution and at the same time it guarantees that no retain cycles will be made

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of `weakSelf` is to ensure that the notification center observer doesn't maintain a strong reference to `AVCamViewController`. The presence of `strongSelf` inside the block is to avoid race conditions where `AVCamViewController` might be deallocated in the middle of a notification (thus if `weakSelf` existed when the notification came in, keep it around for the duration of the processing of the notification; but if `weakSelf` didn't exist when the notification came in, then `strongSelf` would be `nil`, too).

This process (sometimes joking called the "weak self-strong self dance") is critical. If you just have `strongSelf = self`, you've reintroduced the strong reference cycle (previously known as "retain cycle") that the above pattern worked so hard to resolve.